# Geom_text labels not in correct location

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plotly, geom-text

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kajZ.png)

I am using geom_text to add labels onto my bar chart but they are not in the correct locations (seen in the picture). Here is my code:

```
df<-data.frame(Project=datafram$Project,Capex=datafram$Capex,width=datafram$Capex, Emissions=datafram$Emissions)
df$w <- cumsum(df$width) #cumulative sums.
df$wm <- df$w - df$width
df$Emissions<- with(df, wm + (w - wm)/2)

p  <- ggplot(df, aes(ymin = 0))
p1 <- p + geom_rect(aes(xmin = wm, xmax = w, ymax = Emissions, fill = Project))
p2<-p1 + geom_text(aes(x = Capex, y = Emissions, label = Project), size=4, nudge_x = c(0.22,-0.22) ) 
p3<-p2+labs(title = "Abatement Curve", x = "Capex", y = "Capital Efficiency")
g=p3;
p = ggplotly(g);
```

Not sure what I am during wrong. Pls help

Comment: can you share what is in `df` by sharing the output of `dput(df)` please?  Alternatively, share what is in `datafram` (the raw data you started with) via the same method (`dput(datafram)`).

Answer (score 1):

the problem is caused by the `x = Capex` in `geom_text(aes(x = Capex, ...))`. You probably want ggplot to draw the texts in the middle on top of the geom_rects - this can be done like this:

```
df <- data.frame(Project = c("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"), Capex = c(4000, 4000, 1000,2000,10000,1000))
df$w <- cumsum(df$Capex)
df$wm <- df$w - df$Capex
df$Emissions<- with(df, wm + (w - wm)/2)

p <- ggplot(df) +
  geom_rect(aes(ymin = 0, xmin = wm, xmax = w, ymax = Emissions, fill = Project)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = wm + Capex/2, y = Emissions, label = Project), size = 4, nudge_y = 180) +
  labs(title = "Abatement Curve", x = "Capex", y = "Capital Efficiency")
```

With `x = wm + Capex/2` I'm passing the horizontal center of each geom_rect as x-position for the texts.